# Python loop querying MySQL - query results not updated?

Tags: python, mysql

I've got a small bit of python code that queries mySQL,

```
while True:
    print "running SQL query"
    cursor.execute('select * from sites where stage="NEW"')
    results = cursor.fetchall() #Fetch results
    for row in results:
        print "change detected" #simplified line for testing
    print "sleeping"
    sleep(10)
```

When no records match output is :

```
running SQL query
sleeping
running SQL query
sleeping
```

Manually create SQL record that will match (allow time for loop to repeat), output is still :

```
running SQL query
sleeping
running SQL query
sleeping
```

Stop script and restart, test output is as expected :

```
running SQL query
change detected
sleeping
```

So the results are being cached? or the query not being re-run?

How would I deal with this, bearing in mind the query is run quite frequently (I did wonder about closing the DB connection and re-opening everytime, but this seems excessive?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look the [Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-commit.html) for `commit()` it can give a hint on why your code doesn't work.

Try using `database.commit()` after `sleep(10)` and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks, this appears to work. I am still a little confused since my code doesn't write to the database (and I thought a commit was only to apply changes). I'm assuming for now, that even though this code is not making any changes, the commit is 'completing/closing' the current query such that when the query is repeated (in my code), I am looking at a fresh set of results and not the results of the previous query.