# Mysql Connector on Python not noticing database changes in While Loop

Tags: python, mysql

I have a script constantly running to check if a race is open or closed. The script finds an open race by Status = OPEN. Then performs steps on it to close it.

The issue is that in the while loop it does the query and outputs data about it. If a race is OPEN and I change status to close it still keeps outputting the information as if it was OPEN.

I have even deleted the whole record during operation and the same output keeps coming out.

I have tried:

- closing connection after initial query
- setting every variable in the code to None after first lookup
- changing database status field from VARCHAR to INT

  ```
  def findMarketID(self):
  global market_id
  mycursor = mydbr.cursor()
  mycursor.execute("SELECT market_id FROM horses WHERE status = 'OPEN'")
  myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
  mycursor.close()
  for x in myresult:
      market_id = x
  market_id = str(market_id)
  market_id = market_id.strip(" ('")
  market_id = market_id.strip("',) ")
  if market_id is not None:
    print("There is value")
    time.sleep(2)
  else:
    pass
  while True:
      findMarketID()
  ```

Comment: seems like it was db.commit
This answer fixed my issue
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40766333/python-loop-querying-mysql-query-results-not-updated

Comment: thanks for reporting back; I suggested that this question be closed as a duplicate of the question you found - [Python loop querying MySQL - query results not updated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40766333/python-loop-querying-mysql-query-results-not-updated)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40766333/python-loop-querying-mysql-query-results-not-updated